# When I opened a Blazor project using Devexpress template, the project did not work

Tags: visual-studio, web, blazor, devexpress

When I open a blazor project using devexpress template, I get the following error when I run it without making any changes in the code

[image]

I created the project by doing the following process.

[image]

Can you help me to solve this problem.